# Setup method is not being called

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

I've created a starter project with `vue ui` (typescript, babel, linter). Everything works fine, but I can't quite understand how to make **Composition API**'s `setup`method to work. It's simply not being called (log output is empty) Here's where I'm stuck.

- **vue**: 3.0.0-rc.10
- **vue-cli**: 4.5.4

  ```
  <script lang="ts">
   import { Options, Vue } from 'vue-class-component'
   import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'

   @Options({
     components: {
       HelloWorld
     },
     setup () {
       console.log('SETUP HERE')
     }
   })
   export default class App extends Vue {
     setup () {
       console.log('SETUP THERE')
     }
   }
   </script>
  ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should import `setup` from `vue-class-component` then use it like :

```
<template>
  <div>Count: {{ counter.count }}</div>
  <button @click="counter.increment()">+</button>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { ref, reactive, onMounted } from 'vue'
import { Vue, setup } from 'vue-class-component'

function useCounter () {
  const count = ref(0)

  function increment () {
    count.value++
  }

  onMounted(() => {
    console.log('onMounted')
  })

  return {
    count,
    increment
  }
}

export default class Counter extends Vue {
  counter = setup(() => useCounter())
}
</script>
```

for more details please check this [issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/issues/416)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it was caused by extending the child component. The **composition API** (setup method) is never called if you extend the component. While the **options API** lifecycle hooks are called in both components.

```js
// child.js

<script>
import { onMounted } from "vue";

export default {
  name: "ChildComponent",
  setup() {
    console.log('Child - setup()');
    onMounted(() => {
      console.log('Child - mounted (composition API)');
    })
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('Child - mounted (option API)');
  }
}
</script>
```

```js
// parent.js

<script>
import ChildComponent from "./child.js";
import { onMounted } from "vue";

export default {
  name: "ParentComponent",
  extends: ChildComponent,
  setup() {
    console.log('Parent - setup()');
    onMounted(() => {
      console.log('Parent - mounted (composition API)');
    })
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('Parent - mounted (option API)');
  }
}
</script>
```

**OUTPUT**

```js
Parent - setup()
Parent - mounted (composition API)
Child - mounted (option API)
Parent - mounted (option API)
```